# Hierarchical Clustering on pandas giving Value error

Tags: python, pandas, text, hierarchical-clustering

I am using python on clustering text documents which I have as a dataframe. This is what I am doing:

```
from __future__ import division
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_lst = data_rd['text'].values.tolist()
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( max_features=200000, stop_words='english',use_idf=True, tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(' '), ngram_range=(1,3))

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_lst) 
print(tfidf_matrix.shape)
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
dist = 1 - cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)

#(10193, 32757)
linkage_dist=ward(dist)
linkage_matrix = linkage(tfidf_matrix.todense(), 'ward')

dendrogram(linkage_matrix,truncate_mode="lastp",p=40,
show_leaf_counts=True,leaf_rotation=60.,leaf_font_size=8.,
show_contracted=True,  )
is_valid_linkage(linkage_matrix)
is_valid_linkage(linkage_dist)
#False
#False
```

I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py", line 
 2227, in dendrogram
 is_valid_linkage(Z, throw=True, name='Z')
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py", line 
 1421, in is_valid_linkage
 % name_str)
 ValueError: Linkage 'Z' uses the same cluster more than once.
```

is there any other way apart from fastcluster to solve this and why is this happening?
There is a one row in the column that is blank and has no text.

Comment: Please post the full trace of the error you're getting.  Also, it'll be easier to help if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with.

Comment: I cannot provide an example of the dataset, but I can provide information on the same. It has 10193 rows with blobs of text, the dataframe has only one column and i.e the text to cluster. @andrew_reece

Comment: You don't need to supply the actual data - just provide code that generates a dataset that contains the minimal features necessary to reproduce your problem.  You'll be much more likely to get an answer that way.  As it is, it's difficult to debug your issue (also, it looks like you removed `Z` from your example code, which makes the error text confusing).

Comment: The same data when I pass through fastcluster method, it works. it does not give a visual dendrogram though. This problem is particularly interesting as it cannot be replicated with a small dataset or another type of dataset, at the sametime I know people have faced the same problem. [link](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6785) is an example. Also the `Z` in the error is not a variable but implies that its talking about the linkage matrix, no matter how you name your linkage matrix the error will always call it `Z`. I am using Python 2.7- @andrew_reece